# Fastest way to get row number with percentage selects (LIMIT X, 1)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rowcount

In my MySQL database I have a table (PERSONS) with over 10 million rows, the two important columns are:

- ID
- POINTS

I would like to know the rank of the person with ID = *randomid*

I want to return to the person his "rank", which depends on his points. **But** his rank will  not be the exact row number, but more like a percentage layer. Like: "You are in the top 5%" or "You are in the layer 10% - 15%".

Of course I could query the table and convert the row number to the layer% by dividing it with the total number of rows. But my question is, would it be faster (with 10M+ rows) to just grab the several rows with LIMIT X, 1, where X will be a row on percentage 100, 95, 90, 85 .. of the table. Next step: check if the points of this row is lower than the current persons points and if yes, grab next layer % row, if not, return previous layer row.

In the persons table there are 9 columns with 2 bigints, 4 varchars 150, 1 date and 2 booleans.

Of course I would prefer to get the exact row rank, but from what I tested, this is slow and takes at least several seconds, with my wat it can be done in a few hundreds of a second.

Also, the way I suggested is not precise when there are several layers with the same points, but it doesn't need to be that precise, so we can neglect that fact.

Extra info, I program in PHP, so if there is a specific solution for this in PHP + MySQL it would be nice too.

At last, it's worth to mention that the table grows with 20k rows an hour (almost 500k a day).

I appreciate all the help.

Comment: This appears to be a question about mysql and percentiles. Am I right?

Comment: Yes I mean percentiles. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this.  I first count the number of rows with *more* points, and then add one to that, in case there are a number of rows with the same number of points.  So if there are 10 rows with the same number of points, they all have the same rank as the first one in that group.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN points > (SELECT POINTS FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID = randomid) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1 as Rank,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN points > (SELECT POINTS FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID = randomid) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1) / COUNT(*) as Pct
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
```

If that is slow, I would run two queries.  First get that ID's points and then plug that into a second query to determine the rank/pct.

```
SELECT POINTS 
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  ID = randomid
```

Then compute the rank and pct, plugging in the points from above.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN points > POINTS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1 as Rank,
       (SUM(CASE WHEN points > POINTS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + 1) / COUNT(*) as Pct
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: Pct is just what I am calling the percent calculation.  You could call it anything.

Comment: On a test table with 600k rows it is really fast, 0,3 seconds. This is really nice. Is this solution faster than selects with rowcounts? I am quite new to SQL and so I do not fully understand your query :)

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow as well, just so you know.

Comment: There are a number of different ways to do it.  This may not be the fastest, but it's relatively neat.  The fastest way to do it would probably be to make 3 calls and store the results in PHP variables, and then do your math.  First you would get the point count for the ID in question `SELECT POINTS FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ID = randomid`, then get the rank `SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FORM YOUR_TABLE WHERE POINTS > <points from above>`, then get the total recs `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YOUR_TABLE`.